# Erro ao tentar criar um array de objetos

Tags: php, html

estou tentando criar uma array de objetos porém estou recebendo a seguinte mensagem de erro: Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in

Classe

```
class controler {

        private $anuncios = array();
        private $pedidos=   array();
        private $usuarios = array();
}
```

Dentro da classe fiz um método para polular o array com objetos

```
public static function getAnuncios()
        {

            include("conexao.php");


            $query="SELECT * FROM tb_anuncio";



        $result = $conexao->query($query)or die( mysql_error());
       print_r($result);

        if(!isset($anuncios))
        {
            while ($anuncio = mysql_fetch_object($result)) //linha a qual o erro é acusado
            {
               // $obj_anuncio = new anuncio($anuncio['cd_anuncio'],$anuncio['nm_titulo'],$anuncio['ds_anuncio'],$anuncio['cd_usuario'],$anuncio['nm_estado'],$anuncio['nm_cidade'],$anuncio['nm_bairro'],$anuncio['nm_categoria']);



                $anuncios[] = $anuncio;
                foreach ($anuncios as $anuncio)
                 {
                  # code...
               print_r($anuncio->cd_anuncio);




              }

                # code...
            }
            return $anuncios;
            die();
        }

        }
```

Comment: O que tem dentro do `$result` em `$anuncio = mysql_fetch_object($result)`?

Comment: coloquei um print_r($result); para ver o que tinha dentro do result e recebi um retorno correto do banco acredito eu, no print_r mostrou a quantidade de rows o type e etc.

Comment: Não é `mysqli_xxx` em vez de `mysql_xxx`?

Comment: caraca era isso mesmo, não me atentei na hora de usar, vlw